# How do I pass a reference to mutable data in Rust?

Tags: pointers, mutable, rust

I want to create a mutable struct on the stack and mutate it from helper functions.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Game {
    score: u32,
}

fn addPoint(game: &mut Game) {
    game.score += 1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game { score: 0 };

    println!("Initial game: {:?}", game);

    // This works:
    game.score += 1;

    // This gives a compile error:
    addPoint(&game);

    println!("Final game:   {:?}", game);
}
```

Trying to compile this gives:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:14
   |
19 |     addPoint(&game);
   |              ^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut Game`
              found type `&Game`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: convention would have `fn add_point(game: &mut Game)` rather than `fn addPoint (game: &mut Game)`.

Comment: Weird you didn't see the compiler note "expected type `&mut Game`"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reference needs to be marked as mutable too:

```
addPoint(&mut game);
```