# How do I push a value into a 2D Vec in Rust?

Tags: vector, types, rust

Here is a really simple attempt at a 2D `Vec`. I'm trying to add an element to the last entry in the top-level `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec_2d = vec![vec![]];
    if let Some(v) = vec_2d.last() {
        v.push(1);
    }
    println!("{:?}", vec_2d);
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*v` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
3 |     if let Some(v) = vec_2d.last() {
  |                 - help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut std::vec::Vec<i32>`
4 |         v.push(1);
  |         ^ `v` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

I've also tried `Some(ref v)` and `Some(ref mut v)` with the same results. I can't find any documentation that describes this error specifically. What is the right approach here?

An [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574503/777929) recommends something more like `Some(&mut v)`. Then I get these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     if let Some(&mut v) = vec_2d.last() {
  |                 ^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
  = note: expected type `&std::vec::Vec<_>`
             found type `&mut _`
  = help: did you mean `mut v: &&std::vec::Vec<_>`?
```

If I try `Some(&ref mut v)` I get:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:18
  |
3 |     if let Some(&ref mut v) = vec_2d.last() {
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grab a mutable reference to the last element with [`last_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut); no need to change patterns.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec_2d = vec![vec![]];
    if let Some(v) = vec_2d.last_mut() {
        v.push(1);
    }
    println!("{:?}", vec_2d);
}
```

Comment: Some methods can either return a mutable or immutable reference. Those that can usually have the mutable version prefixed with `mut_`, like `.last` and `.mut_last`.

Answer (score 3):

A (much) more elegant solution for this particular case would be:

```
fn main() {
    let vec_2d = vec![vec![1i32]];

    println!("{:?}", vec_2d);
}
```