# Creating a Vector of Vectors in Rust

Tags: matrix, vector, rust

This code won't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let m1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let m2 = vec![&m1, &m1, &m1];
    let m3 = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6], vec![7, 8, 9]];

    for i in &m2 {
        for j in i {
            println!("{}", j);
        }
    }

    for i in &m3 {
        for j in i {
            println!("{}", j);
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&&std::vec::Vec<{integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         for j in i {
  |                  ^ `&&std::vec::Vec<{integer}>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&&std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

1. How is `m2` different than `m3` such that `m3` causes no issues, but `m2` prevents compilation?
2. Is there an easier way to create a vector of vector of... to any desired depth? The way I have it working (`m3`) seems so clunky.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/25151890/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102786/155423.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How is `m2` different than `m3` ...

Check the types step by step. `m1` is of type `Vec<isize>` (it could be any other integer type as well, but I assume it's `isize` for now). Why? Because the elements in the `vec![]` macro are of type `isize`. Now you are creating `m2`:

```
let m2 = vec![&m1, &m1, &m1];
```

What is the type of the elements in this macro? Well we already said `m1` has the type `Vec<isize>`, so `&m1` has the type `&Vec<isize>`. So the resulting type of `m2` is `Vec<&Vec<isize>>` (a vector full of **references** to other vectors).

However, `m3` is of type `Vec<Vec<isize>>`, since the elements in the (outer) `vec![]` macro are of type `Vec<isize>` (no reference!).

*Hint*: [to easily check the type of any variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423) (such as `foo`), type:

```
let _: () = foo;
```

This will result in a compiler error that tells you the type of `foo`.

> ... such that `m3` causes no issues, but `m2` prevents compilation?

Now that we know the types of `m2` and `m3`, lets look at the loops. `for` loops work by accepting something that implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). You are passing `&m2`, which is of type `&Vec<&Vec<isize>>` (note the *two* references). [We can see](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), that `IntoIterator` is indeed implemented for a reference to a vector:

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for &Vec<T> {
    type Item = &T
    // ...
}
```

This means that you get an iterator that spits out references to the inner type `T` (`type Item = &T`). Our inner type of `m2` is `&Vec<isize>`, so we will get items of type `&&Vec<isize>` (two references!). Your variable `i` has this exact type.

Then you want to iterate again with this inner loop:

```
for j in i { ... }
```

But `i` has this double-reference type and there isn't an implementation of `IntoIterator` for that type. To iterate it, you have to either dereference it like:

```
for j in *i { ... }
```

Or even better: make `i` be of the type `&Vec<isize>` (one reference!) by stripping it away with pattern matching in the outer loop:

```
for &i in &m2 { ... }
```

Your `m3` loop does the same, but since `m3` is of another type (with one reference less), it works (I hope you can see why).

---

> Is there an easier way to create a vector of vector of... to any desired depth

Even if `m2` worked, it wouldn't hold the same values as `m3`. To make `m2` of the type `Vec<Vec<isize>>` (like `m3`), you should `clone` `m1` instead of taking a reference to it.

```
let m2 = vec![m1.clone(), m1.clone(), m1.clone()];
```

We can do even better by using the `vec![_; _]` form of the macro:

```
let m2 = vec![m1; 3];   // three times the value of `m1`
```

As a last note, you should consider *not* using nested `Vec`s. The nesting creates overhead because the values are spread over the whole memory instead of being in one place.

Comment: A couple of things...

1) Thanks for your help! I appreciate the prompt and thorough response.
2) Sorry if there was confusion regarding the tripple m1's. I didn't actual intend on doing it that way, but I didn't want to create extra variables and add extra noise to the example.
3) I only chose to nest vectors because the homework assignment I found online (<-gotta love nice cheap practice problems) required this.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add `iter` function to second `for`

```rust
fn main() {
    let m1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let m2 = vec![&m1, &m1, &m1];
    let m3 = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6], vec![7, 8, 9]];

    for i in &m2 {
        for j in i.iter() {
            println!("{}", j);
        }
    }

    for i in &m3 {
        for j in i {
            println!("{}", j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to SO.
While this might solve the problem, could you aswell provide a short explanation of why it's a solution